# Beginner Python help on syntax regarding \

Tags: python-3.x

Why does Python print the \ when there is no print command, but doesn't when there is a print command?  I understand this may just be how it works, but if there is some logic that would be good to know.

```
>>> '"Isn\'t," she said.'
'"Isn\'t," she said.'
>>> print('"Isn\'t," she said.')
"Isn't," she said.
```

Thanks.

JT

Comment: You are looking at the `repr()` output, which represents strings as *Python string literal syntax*. You can copy that and paste it into a Python program and it'll produce the same string value. That requires escaping embedded quotes in this case.

Comment: Note that this behaviour has nothing to do with IDLE. You'll see it in any interactive Python prompt, or you can use `print(repr('"Isn\'t," she said.'))`.

Comment: By why does using print() change it?

Comment: The ``\`` is not part of the *value*. Only part of the notation to produce the string.

Comment: Oh, I understand now I think. repr() just regurgitates what you've typed and print() has logic built into it?  And when you just hit return in IDLE after typing a screen it uses repr()?

Comment: *string, not screen.  Can't edit.

Comment: Yes, in the interactive interpreter, values are echoed by showing their `repr()` result.

Answer (score 0):

When you type directly into the editor it's like saying "This is the exact value i want output". When you call the print function, it "processes" the variable to print what it should be